# How to add watermark for images in Code igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, watermark

I am trying to add water mark for images in Code igniter. But failed all the methods or water mark is not adding.

I am using drag and drop multi image uploading feature.

How can i do it?

Comment: Please edit your question with code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try codeigniter watermark library.

> link :
>   https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html

function is `$this->image_lib->watermark()`

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna add watermark, i suggest codeigniter image_lib class also like @dev87 .
You can use like this function:

```
    /**
 * https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html?highlight=water#watermarking-an-image
 */
public function AddWaterMark($image_url = NULL, $watermark_url = NULL)
{
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $config['source_image'] = $image_url;
    $config['new_image'] = $image_url;
    $config['wm_overlay_path'] = $watermark_url;

    $config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
    //the overlay image
    $config['wm_opacity'] = 90;
    $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
    $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'right';
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

    $this->image_lib->watermark();
}
```

This code will put your watermark image to $image_url pathed image. You can say at bottom and right. please look codeigniter documentation.